# Oracle: Optimising Date and Time conditions, TRUNC and TO_CHAR take too long

Tags: sql, oracle, date, time, to-char

i have an sql statement, that takes just too long.
so i've been digging into it lately, and found that the problem was on a single column of type DATE

this is a miniature of the first statement :

```
SELECT 
  --needed values --
FROM X_Product pr
INNER JOIN Z_COST co ON co.x_product_id = pr.x_product_id
WHERE pr.isValid = 'Y'
AND TRUNC(sysdate, 'MM') - 1   = co.dateto;
```

with this set of where condition the original (long statement) takes about 37 seconds to run.


when i remove the last condition, so we get :

```
SELECT 
  --needed values --
FROM X_Product pr
INNER JOIN Z_COST co ON co.x_product_id = pr.x_product_id
WHERE pr.isValid = 'Y';
```

it takes only 2 seconds.
i've tried to use different kinds of functions as TO_CHAR, and get only the months, i tried to add "TRUNC(sysdate, 'MM') - 1" and "co.dateto" to the selects, then in another select verify if they are equal.
i created indexes on the column, and also on a function on the column.
but it always takes too long.
so i'm running out of ideas, and can't seem to find another way.
and appreciate any help.

Edit : 
the full query : (a long one lol)

```
SELECT mp.AD_CLIENT_ID,
w.AD_ORG_ID,
mp.CREATED,
mp.CREATEDBY,
mp.UPDATED,
mp.UPDATEDBY,
(SELECT MAX(mpl.WINF_LOCATION)
FROM m_productlocator mpl
WHERE mpl.M_PRODUCT_ID =mp.M_PRODUCT_ID
AND mpl.AD_ORG_ID      =w.AD_ORG_ID
) AS WINF_LOCATION,
mp.m_product_id,
mp.value,
mpc.m_product_category_id,
mpc.name AS Product_Category ,
w.m_warehouse_id ,
winf_getproduct_stock( mp.m_product_id, w.m_warehouse_id )                                                                       AS stock_qty ,
z_getproduct_customstock( mp.m_product_id, w.m_warehouse_id )                                                                    AS customStockQty,
winf_get_po_price_org_f( mp.m_product_id, w.ad_org_id )                                                                          AS po_price ,
ROUND( winf_getproduct_stock( mp.m_product_id, w.m_warehouse_id ) * winf_get_po_price_org_f( mp.m_product_id, w.ad_org_id ), 2 ) AS po_value ,
acsch.C_AcctSchema_id ,
ROUND(
-- new cost mc.currentcostprice
mc.nextmonthcost -- new cost
,2) AS Costing_AveragePoPrice ,
ROUND (winf_getproduct_stock( mp.m_product_id, w.m_warehouse_id ) *
-- new cost mc.currentcostprice
mc.nextmonthcost -- new cost
,2) AS Costing_AveragePOValue,
mp.discontinued,
Winf_GetOSGGroup(1000052,mp.m_product_category_id) AS OsgGroup,
po.C_BPartner_ID
FROM m_product mp
--  CROSS JOIN m_warehouse w
-- put as comment by Laurent on 25/09/14 because speed issue

--modif Laurent 25/09/14 because speed issue
inner join m_storage_v s on mp.m_product_id=s.m_product_id
inner join m_locator l on l.m_locator_id=s.m_locator_id
inner join m_warehouse w on w.m_warehouse_id=l.m_warehouse_id
--fin de modif

INNER JOIN C_AcctSchema acsch  ON acsch.ad_orgonly_id = w."AD_ORG_ID"
INNER JOIN m_product_category mpc  ON mpc.m_product_category_id = mp.m_product_category_id
LEFT JOIN z_costing_product mc  ON mc.m_product_id = mp.m_product_id
LEFT JOIN Z_COSTING_CALCUL cc  ON CC.Z_COSTING_CALCUL_ID  = mc.Z_COSTING_CALCUL_ID  AND cc.c_acctschema_id  = acsch.c_acctschema_id
left outer join m_product_po po on po.m_product_id = mp.m_product_id and po.ad_org_id = w.ad_org_id and po.iscurrentvendor = 'Y'
WHERE winf_getproduct_stock( mp.m_product_id, w.m_warehouse_id ) <> 0
AND TRUNC(sysdate, 'MM') - 1                                      = cc.dateto;
```

Edit 2 :

Edit : Full explain plan

```
Plan hash value: 2645911395

   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Id  | Operation                          | Name                    | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                   |                         |  5786K|  1743M|       |  1210K  (2)| 04:02:04 |
   |   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE                    |                         |     1 |    24 |       |            |          |
   |*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID      | M_PRODUCTLOCATOR        |     1 |    24 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
   |*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                | FK915_16182             |     2 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
   |*  4 |  HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER             |                         |  5786K|  1743M|    45M|  1210K  (2)| 04:02:04 |
   |*  5 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL                | M_PRODUCT_PO            |  1483K|    28M|       |  7707   (1)| 00:01:33 |
   |*  6 |   HASH JOIN                        |                         |  5786K|  1633M|       |  1116K  (2)| 03:43:13 |
   |   7 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID     | Z_COSTING_CALCUL        |     9 |   252 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
   |*  8 |     INDEX SKIP SCAN                | Z_COSTING_CALCUL_DATETO |     1 |       |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
   |*  9 |    VIEW                            |                         |   364M|    90G|       |  1114K  (2)| 03:42:52 |
   |* 10 |     HASH JOIN                      |                         |   364M|    64G|       |  1114K  (2)| 03:42:52 |
   |  11 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL             | M_PRODUCT_CATEGORY      |  1957 | 76323 |       |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
   |* 12 |      HASH JOIN OUTER               |                         |   364M|    51G|   139M|  1112K  (1)| 03:42:31 |
   |* 13 |       HASH JOIN                    |                         |   986K|   127M|       | 57859   (1)| 00:11:35 |
   |  14 |        VIEW                        | index$_join$_009        |    20 |   240 |       |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |
   |* 15 |         HASH JOIN                  |                         |       |       |       |            |          |
   |* 16 |          INDEX FAST FULL SCAN      | FK265_14205             |    20 |   240 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
   |  17 |          INDEX FAST FULL SCAN      | PK265                   |    20 |   240 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
   |* 18 |        HASH JOIN                   |                         |  1281K|   151M|       | 57849   (1)| 00:11:35 |
   |  19 |         INDEX FULL SCAN            | Z_WAREHOUSE_10          |   291 |  3492 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
   |* 20 |         HASH JOIN                  |                         |  1281K|   136M|       | 57842   (1)| 00:11:35 |
   |  21 |          INDEX FULL SCAN           | Z_LOCATOR_30            |   283 |  3396 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
   |* 22 |          HASH JOIN                 |                         |  1291K|   123M|    46M| 57834   (1)| 00:11:35 |
   |  23 |           VIEW                     | M_STORAGE_V             |  1291K|    32M|       | 41216   (1)| 00:08:15 |
   |  24 |            HASH GROUP BY           |                         |  1291K|    91M|   104M| 41216   (1)| 00:08:15 |
   |* 25 |             HASH JOIN              |                         |  1291K|    91M|       | 18710   (1)| 00:03:45 |
   |  26 |              VIEW                  | index$_join$_020        |   283 |  3396 |       |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |
   |* 27 |               HASH JOIN            |                         |       |       |       |            |          |
   |  28 |                INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| FK207_1390              |   283 |  3396 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
   |  29 |                INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| PK207                   |   283 |  3396 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
   |* 30 |              HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER |                         |  1301K|    76M|    33M| 18701   (1)| 00:03:45 |
   |  31 |               TABLE ACCESS FULL    | M_PRODUCT               |   679K|    25M|       | 11466   (1)| 00:02:18 |
   |  32 |               TABLE ACCESS FULL    | M_STORAGEDETAIL         |  1301K|    27M|       |  3453   (1)| 00:00:42 |
   |  33 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL        | M_PRODUCT               |   679K|    47M|       | 11514   (1)| 00:02:19 |
   |  34 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL            | Z_COSTING_PRODUCT       |   251M|  3598M|       |   723K  (2)| 02:24:46 |
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
   ---------------------------------------------------

      2 - filter("MPL"."AD_ORG_ID"=:B1)
      3 - access("MPL"."M_PRODUCT_ID"=:B1)
      4 - access("PO"."AD_ORG_ID"(+)="from$_subquery$_014"."QCSJ_C000000000800003" AND 
                 "PO"."M_PRODUCT_ID"(+)="from$_subquery$_014"."QCSJ_C000000000400008")
      5 - filter("PO"."ISCURRENTVENDOR"(+)='Y')
      6 - access("CC"."C_ACCTSCHEMA_ID"="ACSCH"."C_ACCTSCHEMA_ID" AND 
                 "CC"."Z_COSTING_CALCUL_ID"="MC"."Z_COSTING_CALCUL_ID")
      8 - access("CC"."DATETO"=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmmm')-1)
          filter("CC"."DATETO"=TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmmm')-1 AND 
                 TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("DATETO"),'fmmm')=TRUNC(TRUNC(SYSDATE@!,'fmmm')-1,'fmmm'))
      9 - filter("WINF_GETPRODUCT_STOCK"("from$_subquery$_014"."QCSJ_C000000000400008","from$_subquery$_014"."QCS
                 J_C000000000800007")<>0)
     10 - access("MPC"."M_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID"="MP"."M_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID")
     12 - access("MC"."M_PRODUCT_ID"(+)="MP"."M_PRODUCT_ID")
     13 - access("ACSCH"."AD_ORGONLY_ID"="W"."AD_ORG_ID")
     15 - access(ROWID=ROWID)
     16 - filter("ACSCH"."AD_ORGONLY_ID" IS NOT NULL)
     18 - access("W"."M_WAREHOUSE_ID"="L"."M_WAREHOUSE_ID")
     20 - access("L"."M_LOCATOR_ID"="S"."M_LOCATOR_ID")
     22 - access("MP"."M_PRODUCT_ID"="S"."M_PRODUCT_ID")
     25 - access("L"."M_LOCATOR_ID"="ST"."M_LOCATOR_ID")
     27 - access(ROWID=ROWID)
     30 - access("P"."M_PRODUCT_ID"(+)="ST"."M_PRODUCT_ID")
```

after removing the last where condition :

```
AND TRUNC(sysdate, 'MM') - 1            = cc.dateto;
```

The explain plan for it is : 
    Plan hash value: 1172089290

```
     -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     | Id  | Operation                          | Name               | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
     -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                   |                    |   364M|   101G|       |  5950K  (1)| 19:50:06 |
     |   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE                    |                    |     1 |    24 |       |            |          |
     |*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID      | M_PRODUCTLOCATOR   |     1 |    24 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
     |*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                | FK915_16182        |     2 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
     |*  4 |  HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER             |                    |   364M|   101G|       |  5950K  (1)| 19:50:06 |
     |   5 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL                | Z_COSTING_CALCUL   |   535 |  6420 |       |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
     |*  6 |   HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER            |                    |   364M|    97G|    45M|  5948K  (1)| 19:49:45 |
     |*  7 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL               | M_PRODUCT_PO       |  1483K|    28M|       |  7707   (1)| 00:01:33 |
     |*  8 |    VIEW                            |                    |   364M|    90G|       |  1114K  (2)| 03:42:52 |
     |*  9 |     HASH JOIN                      |                    |   364M|    64G|       |  1114K  (2)| 03:42:52 |
     |  10 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL             | M_PRODUCT_CATEGORY |  1957 | 76323 |       |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
     |* 11 |      HASH JOIN OUTER               |                    |   364M|    51G|   139M|  1112K  (1)| 03:42:31 |
     |* 12 |       HASH JOIN                    |                    |   986K|   127M|       | 57859   (1)| 00:11:35 |
     |  13 |        VIEW                        | index$_join$_009   |    20 |   240 |       |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |
     |* 14 |         HASH JOIN                  |                    |       |       |       |            |          |
     |* 15 |          INDEX FAST FULL SCAN      | FK265_14205        |    20 |   240 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
     |  16 |          INDEX FAST FULL SCAN      | PK265              |    20 |   240 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
     |* 17 |        HASH JOIN                   |                    |  1281K|   151M|       | 57849   (1)| 00:11:35 |
     |  18 |         INDEX FULL SCAN            | Z_WAREHOUSE_10     |   291 |  3492 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
     |* 19 |         HASH JOIN                  |                    |  1281K|   136M|       | 57842   (1)| 00:11:35 |
     |  20 |          INDEX FULL SCAN           | Z_LOCATOR_30       |   283 |  3396 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
     |* 21 |          HASH JOIN                 |                    |  1291K|   123M|    46M| 57834   (1)| 00:11:35 |
     |  22 |           VIEW                     | M_STORAGE_V        |  1291K|    32M|       | 41216   (1)| 00:08:15 |
     |  23 |            HASH GROUP BY           |                    |  1291K|    91M|   104M| 41216   (1)| 00:08:15 |
     |* 24 |             HASH JOIN              |                    |  1291K|    91M|       | 18710   (1)| 00:03:45 |
     |  25 |              VIEW                  | index$_join$_020   |   283 |  3396 |       |     3  (34)| 00:00:01 |
     |* 26 |               HASH JOIN            |                    |       |       |       |            |          |
     |  27 |                INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| FK207_1390         |   283 |  3396 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
     |  28 |                INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| PK207              |   283 |  3396 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
     |* 29 |              HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER |                    |  1301K|    76M|    33M| 18701   (1)| 00:03:45 |
     |  30 |               TABLE ACCESS FULL    | M_PRODUCT          |   679K|    25M|       | 11466   (1)| 00:02:18 |
     |  31 |               TABLE ACCESS FULL    | M_STORAGEDETAIL    |  1301K|    27M|       |  3453   (1)| 00:00:42 |
     |  32 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL        | M_PRODUCT          |   679K|    47M|       | 11514   (1)| 00:02:19 |
     |  33 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL            | Z_COSTING_PRODUCT  |   251M|  3598M|       |   723K  (2)| 02:24:46 |
     -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

     Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
     ---------------------------------------------------

        2 - filter("MPL"."AD_ORG_ID"=:B1)
        3 - access("MPL"."M_PRODUCT_ID"=:B1)
        4 - access("CC"."C_ACCTSCHEMA_ID"(+)="ACSCH"."C_ACCTSCHEMA_ID" AND 
                   "CC"."Z_COSTING_CALCUL_ID"(+)="MC"."Z_COSTING_CALCUL_ID")
        6 - access("PO"."AD_ORG_ID"(+)="from$_subquery$_014"."QCSJ_C000000000800003" AND 
                   "PO"."M_PRODUCT_ID"(+)="from$_subquery$_014"."QCSJ_C000000000400008")
        7 - filter("PO"."ISCURRENTVENDOR"(+)='Y')
        8 - filter("WINF_GETPRODUCT_STOCK"("from$_subquery$_014"."QCSJ_C000000000400008","from$_subquery$_014"
                   ."QCSJ_C000000000800007")<>0)
        9 - access("MPC"."M_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID"="MP"."M_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_ID")
       11 - access("MC"."M_PRODUCT_ID"(+)="MP"."M_PRODUCT_ID")
       12 - access("ACSCH"."AD_ORGONLY_ID"="W"."AD_ORG_ID")
       14 - access(ROWID=ROWID)
       15 - filter("ACSCH"."AD_ORGONLY_ID" IS NOT NULL)
       17 - access("W"."M_WAREHOUSE_ID"="L"."M_WAREHOUSE_ID")
       19 - access("L"."M_LOCATOR_ID"="S"."M_LOCATOR_ID")
       21 - access("MP"."M_PRODUCT_ID"="S"."M_PRODUCT_ID")
       24 - access("L"."M_LOCATOR_ID"="ST"."M_LOCATOR_ID")
       26 - access(ROWID=ROWID)
       29 - access("P"."M_PRODUCT_ID"(+)="ST"."M_PRODUCT_ID")
```

Comment: Are you measuring the time until the *first* row is returned or until the *last* row is returned?  This can make a big difference.

Comment: 'it takes only 2 seconds.' ... to what, get the entire resultset, or just the first X rows?

Comment: Have you used `EXPLAIN PLAN`? Might be useful to see how the query executes

Comment: have you tried an index on z_cost of (x_product_id, dateto)?

Comment: I would definitely use dbms_xplan.display_cursor to understand the difference in execution plans being produced by the 2 queries.  Symptoms seem to indicate that Oracle is underestimating how many rows your dateto filter will return, and is choosing Z_COST as the driving table in the first query which is less than optimal, and something updated statistics may resolve.  However, I would confirm this before just blindly gathering stats :)

Comment: What are the cardinalities of records with "isValid = 'Y'", and records with "TRUNC(sysdate, 'MM') - 1   = co.dateto"? As the previous commenters also suspect there may be a wrong decision of the optimizer, which could be found by the explain plan, and the real cardinalities.

Comment: @GordonLinoff to get the full result set, aroung 10k rows

Comment: @Galcoholic most "dateTo"s are null

Comment: @Boneist       yep, takes the same time, however the access on the table z_cost is no longer "FullAccess" but "Index"

Comment: Please, send us an "EXPLAIN PLAN FOR" output for both statements.

Comment: @Galcoholic it is on the edit now, i'll put the plan without the last condition

Comment: now the full plan, turned out, there are more than one performance issue